# Execute commands against list of items in file in bash

Tags: bash

I have a file listing 1 or more server's hostnames `hostname_list` that I generate using `grep` and `awk`. Now I need to execute `salt` commands against the hostnames. I am trying, as a test, to run `test.ping` to ping each server in the list.

I have tried doing it as a for loop but I can't get it to work.

I've tried numerous variations of:

```
for i in hostname_list
do 
    salt $i test.ping
done
```

Comment: Is `hostname_list` the name of a text file containing the names? Or a command that generates such a text file to standard output? Or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under assumption that `hostname_list` is a text file containing 1 hostname per line, you can use this:

```
while read -r line
do
    [[ -n "$line" ]] && salt $line test.ping
done < hostname_list
```

The `[[ -n "$line" ]]` statement checks that the line is not empty before executing the following command.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thank you!